# Why calling a simple method in SpringMVC service super slow than static method every time?

Tags: java, spring, profiling, benchmarking, static-methods

It cost too many milliseconds enter a method and exit from that method in SpringMVC service. But If I modify the method to static it costs only 1 milliseconds.
Our project is a SpringMVC-Mybatis project.I found that the controller cost about 70 milliseconds to enter a service method and exit from that method.
The method get a value from a static map with 128 keys.

```
@Controller 
public class OrdersController extends BaseAction
{
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private CompanyService<Company> companyService; 

    public void validateInfo()
    {
            Company company = CompanyService.queryByIdFromCache(account);// cost about 70 milliseconds, but if the method is static it is 1 milliseconds.
    }
```

### }

```
@Service("companyService")
public class CompanyService<T> extends BaseService<T> 
{

    private static ConcurrentMap<Integer, Company>cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); //map with 128 keys

    public Company queryByIdFromCache(Integer id)
    {
        return cache.get(id);
    }
}
```

I expect the method finish withint 2 milliseconds.
The service work on singleton mode. And companyService is same instance.
I don't want to modify all method to static method, because some code must be called with non-static way.

Comment: One possible explanation would be that Spring Beans are created as proxies. Thus, they can't proxy `static` methods. This means that if the method is `static`, it will not be proxied and thus will not have to be intercepted (which costs additional time and resources). You might take try and set a breakpoint inside the method and use something like `AopUtils.isAopProxy()` or similar methods to verify this.

Comment: how did you measure to begin with?

Comment: @Eugene What exactly does `JIT` have to do with determining whether his `OrdersController` is being proxied by Spring or not?

Comment: @user991710, I will try it. thank you.

Comment: @Eugene: Sorry,  I have delete the log.

Comment: @user991710: I have verify AopUtils.isAopProxy() is false.But I have configured transaction  on service as:   <aop:config>  
        <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* com.rwxz.biz.service..*.*(..))"  advice-ref="txAdvice" />  
    </aop:config>

Comment: @user3352389 so your method is indercepted by a transactional proxy. You're thus measuring very different things. One just returns a value from a cache. The other starts a transaction, gets the value from a cache, then commits the transaction. This method has no reason to be transactional.

Comment: @user991710:Yes.I see. But some other methods I need to update data of MySQL.Now I will try to use directly MySQL connection for performance. If you have some way to improve performance of if, please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that an aspect is intercepting the call to the non-static service method.

There are a few ways to profile the executions and find the hot spot for your service call. I used NetBeans's Test Profiler to replicate this issue.

First, I created static (component) and non-static services:

```java
@Service
public class DemoService {

    private static final ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public DemoService() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
            CACHE.put(i, String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }

    public String queryByIdFromCache(Integer id) {
        return CACHE.getOrDefault(id, "");
    }

}


public class DemoStaticService {

    private static final ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
            CACHE.put(i, String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }

    public static String queryByIdFromCache(Integer id) {
        return CACHE.getOrDefault(id, "");
    }

}
```

Then I created a controller with two actions, one invoking the non-static, injected service and one invoking the service that uses a static method:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/demo")
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    private DemoService demoService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/demo")
    public String callService(@RequestParam Integer id) {
        return demoService.queryByIdFromCache(id);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/static-demo")
    public String callStaticService(@RequestParam Integer id) {
        return DemoStaticService.queryByIdFromCache(id);
    }

}
```

After that, I wrote two unit tests to help me with profiling the service methods:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private DemoController demoController;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        demoController.callService(1);
        demoController.callStaticService(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallService() {
        for (int id = 0; id < 128; id++) {
            demoController.callService(id);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallStaticService() {
        for (int id = 0; id < 128; id++) {
            demoController.callStaticService(id);
        }
    }

}
```

When the test file was open, I selected the `Profile -> Profile Test File` menu item:

[image: Profile Test File]

Then from the `▶ Profile` drop down, I selected the `Methods` option:

[image: Profile Dropdown]

Finally I clicked on the `▶ Profile` button to profile the tests. I got this result, which shows that the call to the injected service is only 50% more expensive than the call to the static method:

[image: Profile 1]

But what if the second method was intercepted by an aspect (e.g. `@Transactional`)?

To test this, I updated the `DemoService` and made its method transactional

```java
@Service
public class DemoService {

    private static final ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public DemoService() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
            CACHE.put(i, String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public String queryByIdFromCache(Integer id) {
        return CACHE.getOrDefault(id, "");
    }

}
```

After re-running the tests, I got this profiling result this time:

[image: Profile 2]

As it can be seen, the transactional aspect has made the call to `DemoService.queryByIdFromCache` about 14.5 (10.2/0.708) times slower.

To find the root cause for the slowdown in your service method, I suggest you to setup a similar test and profile it with NetBeans Profiler (or something similar).

Comment: thanks a lot. I have set log4j debug level to trace and found the reason is aop intercept begin transaction before real enter the method and commit transaction after return.Because the performance is so critical for us, I decide to call low level api directly from mysql-connector-java.